# Sending data between computers on different networks C#

Tags: c#, winforms, networking, sharing

I was interested on making a basic vpn system so I went on the lookout for some C# code that would allow me to share data between computers on different networks. I thought i had it but I can't get it to work across other networks:

```
ShowCapital sh;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TcpClientChannel channel = new TcpClientChannel();

        ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, false);

        RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownClientType(
            typeof(ShowCapital), "tcp://203.184.17.120:1234    /Showcapital");
        sh = new ShowCapital();


    }
```

Just to clarify: this example script exchanges country data, that's why the confusing variable names.

Basically i don't know what to fill in after "tcp://" in order to get data to transfer over different networks. Only local IP address seem to work.

(By the way, i'm kind of ish new to coding)
Just in case it wasn't clear, this is on winforms.

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: Is there a basic VPN system?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. i just followed a tutorial on data sharing between computers: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K0ncj74YFto. the code is the exact same, i just changed the client to send over a google link and the server to google it and send back the htlm.

Comment: VPN is when connect two private networks across a public WAN. I don't think that is what your tutorial was about. Computers on different networks can't communicate with each other. I think this is more of a networking question than a stack overflow question.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't know. Any ideas on where i could possibly get some insight on the topic. because i am complete stuck on transferring data between computers in C#

Comment: Okay, the code you are showing is to do with [.Net Remoting API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.0/72x4h507(v=vs.85)), that is now obsolete, and legacy, and old like Winforms. This is one of the better places to ask questions about it. If you want to know how IP address work, via LAN and the internet and what VPN tunnels achieve I'm a bit more stuck. However, [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) might be the place to start.

Comment: Thank you so much, i'll leave the question up incase what i was trying is possible and someone knows how. but I will do some reading and hopefully it covers what i was wondering. (Coding is hard to learn without a teacher :) )

Comment: .Net Remoting was integrated into and superseded by [WCF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/migrating-from-net-remoting-to-wcf). It is obviously possible to communicate between computers on different LANs via the internet, I'm doing it now. However, once I connect to the internet are we on different networks or the same global network. Using IPv4, this is achieved by [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) and other technologies but that is all off-topic on this site.

Comment: There are machines on different networks, whether fire-walled or disconnected and the simplest way to communicate with them is via USB drive, if enabled. More securely, the gap can be spanned using other means involving human intervention.